# Plugging elastic search to my ibm cloudant app

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, cloudant

I have [an app](http://nicolas.huleux.free.fr/pouchdb4/) on cloudant :

How can i plug an elastic search online version, for making full text queries  ?

I want to use the river plug in because the new one is too complex .

For now, the only way for me is to do it on localhost, and install elastic 1.6 on localhost, but i'd like to be able to make queries directly online.

Maybe I should use a LUCENT javascript library for couchDb  instead ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem you're solving here? Cloudant has sophisticated built-in full-text indexing capabilities on top of Lucene:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search

Whilst it's possible to hook ES onto the Cloudant changes feed, it seems like an overly complex solution that gains little advantage compared with Cloudant's built-in Lucene.

Comment: aw thanks a lot, so you mean that elastic search is useless in my case ? Is  the cloudant search API as performant than elastic search  ?

Comment: It's hard to say conclusively with the information you've given. If you give some examples of your data and the kind of searches you want to be able to do, I may be able to give a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot i think it answers my question, i'm going to use the link you have provided, thank you.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if you think it solved your problem so others can benefit, too -- many thanks.